# WPF: How to update UserControl within a ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf-controls

I have a problem modifying a ListBox that contains a collection of UserControls.  I want to update a particular UserControl item, but it's not being updated when the binding class has changed.

Class Code:

```
private ObservableCollection<User> _UserList;
    public ObservableCollection<User> UserList
    {
        get
        {
            return _UserList;

        }
        set
        {
            _UserList = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public void EditUser()
    {           
        User wat = UserList.FirstOrDefault(ul => ul.Handle == "JaviSRK");
        wat.Color = "Red";
        NotifyPropertyChanged("UserList");
    }
```

XAML:

```
<ListBox Margin="10,0,0,0" Name="lstLocalUsers" Height="510" Width="225"
  HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding UserList}" SelectionMode="Multiple">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">             
            <tplayer:UserControl />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

UserControl XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Foreground="{Binding Color}" Name="txtLastName" Text="{Binding LastName}" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <TextBlock Foreground="{Binding Color}" Text=", " />
            <TextBlock Foreground="{Binding Color}" Name="txtFirstName" Text="{Binding FirstName}" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <TextBlock Foreground="{Binding Color}" Name="txtHandle" Text="{Binding Handle, StringFormat=({0})}" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="5,0,0,0" />
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Foreground="{Binding Color}" Name="txtCity" Text="{Binding City}" />
            <TextBlock Foreground="{Binding Color}" Text=", " />
            <TextBlock Foreground="{Binding Color}" Name="txtState" Text="{Binding State}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

The UserList collection gets updated properly, but the UserControl itself doesn't.  How do I go about this?

Comment: _"but it's not being updated properly."_ - a bit vague

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the User class itself needed to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged  interface.

```
public class User : INotifyPropertyChanged
{       
    public string _Color;
    public string Color
    {
        get
        {
            return _Color;
        }
        set
        {
            _Color = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }        
}
```